# SharedPreferences. Android, Java

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm sorry, I have a really newby question, but I think it's ok since I'm new in Android developing (in developing at all).
I'm learning how to save my Preferences now. I have a simple application:

```
package com.foxysoft.prefssimple;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final static String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    TextView tvInfo;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
        Boolean notif = sp.getBoolean("notif", false);
        String address = sp.getString("address", "");
        String text = "Notifications are " + ((notif) ? "enabled, address = " + address : "disabled");
        tvInfo.setText(text);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Prefs");
        mi.setIntent(new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a small menu and Activity for my Preferences (PrefActivity.class) and prefs.xml for my Preferences activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="notif"
        android:summary="Enable notifications"
        android:title="Notifications">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="address"
        android:summary="Address for notifications"
        android:title="Address">
    </EditTextPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

So, my question is.
I have two lines in my onResume:

```
Boolean notif = sp.getBoolean("notif", false);
String address = sp.getString("address", "");
```

If I understand it right, it should do my "notif" checkbox false and "address" string "" (empty) everytime onResume called.. Or?..
If no - why? These two line are definitely saying "do notif false and address empty", am I right?

Comment: Yes, These values will be "notif" = false and "address" = empty till that you didn't save anything to these keys. Because at the time of retrieving you are passing default values as false for notify and empty string for address.

Comment: `... am I right?` **No**. They say: "make notif equal to the saved preference value - or set it false if not found" same for the string. The default value is applied if no corresponding value is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are not right - as you are **reading** your **stored** preferences.

When there is no preference named "notif"; then the *default* that you provide to that method call is used; and false will be returned. But if there is a saved preference "notif", then the **value** saved for that will be returned.

Just read the corresponding [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) for that method; it says:

*defValue boolean: Value to return if this preference does not exist.*

*Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue.*

In other words: if you stored `true` before, then that value will be returned.

Besides, the **real** answer here is: there is no need on your side to **assume** how Android API calls work - all of that is nicely documented. So when in doubt, turn to the Javadoc. (and of course - although we try to be really accurate when answering questions - you still could receive a wrong answer here. the only thing that *really* matters is what the API docs say!)

Comment: Haha, ofc i will, it says I should wait 5 mins to accept your answer! Thank you once again.

Comment: I think if I ask a really detailed question I can get my answer asap :) Your answer is accepted now btw!

Comment: The trick is to have all **necessary** details; but not more ;-)